# How to get network information like IP, Gateway, DNS, etc?

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, networking, dns, ip

I need a script, or even better, a single command to get the following information:

```
eth0
     assign: dhcp
    address: 192.168.0.4
    netmask: 255.255.255.0
    gateway: 192.168.0.1
        dns: 8.8.8.8

eth1
     assign: static
    address: 10.0.2.4
    netmask: 255.255.255.0
    gateway: 10.0.2.1
        dns: 8.8.4.4
```

Is this possible, or an utopy? Using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: `ifconfig` (adding words here because solution is so simple that it doesn't even fit into minimum length requirements)

Comment: But `ifconfig` is not deprecated?

Comment: `ip address; grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf` will also work.

Comment: @DopeGhoti what about dhcp dns?

Comment: What should happen if the interface has multiple IP addresses? Are you only interested in IPv4 or do you want IPv6 too? What about handling multiple DNS nameservers? Oh, and what about the situation where one or more elements are not present? DNS doesn't belong to an interface, so should the same information be replicated for all interfaces? Please update your question to explain what output should be produced in these situations.

Comment: If the host is configured to accept DHCP-provided DNS configuration, it will be applied to `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Answer (score 2):

`ip addr show` will show you your interface IP address and broadcast address.

`ip route show` will show the default gateway

To show your current DNS servers, you should try `cat /etc/resolv.conf`